scheme- recursion and built-ins
The built-in status of add1 and sub1
permits the implementation of a recursive process
to effect the math for "(+o, -o, *o)
BUT, when I "analyze" the "(/o, it appears that this entails
"using a fun to 'code' itself (DIVISION*) within itself,"
without the use of a reductive recursion per sub1.
(define /o                         
 (lambda (x y)                     
   (if (< x y)                    
       0                                                          
       (add1 (/o (- x y) y)))))   
(print (/o 10 3))                   

                                 ;;ie. step#1 take the first y "out of" x, per (- x y)
                                            2 take the rest of the y's out of x per (/ x y)
                                            3 add 1 to the (remaining y's) 
                                              ie. adding 1 to x/(- x y) means add the 1st y

                                ;;NB i'm not sure if this is not a "recursive" pattern 
                                     since, there is no sub1 recursion 
                                               ;;[ [? is an '(if  a form of recursion 
                                 and since the initial operation -> retVal
   
                                     run fun until (< x y)              
                                       (+ (/ 7 3) 1) -> 3        ;;x still > y  (7 > 3)
                                     ;;(+ (/ 3 3) 1) -> 2        ;;x still > y  (3 > 2)
                                     ;;(+ (/ 2 3) 1) -> 0        ;;x now   < y  (2 < 3)
                            

I was expecting "(/o to avoid implementing itself, and have recourse to the reductive recursion (sub1 y)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
